# IPFS: Add file in frontend through public gateway, pin file in backend by its CID

Tags: infura, ipfs, frontend, pinata

This is more of a generic question.

I want to give people the chance to upload their file through my front-end using "ipfs-http-client":

```
var ipfs = ipfsHttpClient.create('https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0');
```

After the upload, the CID of the file is sent to my backend and validated there. If the file passes all requirements it is pinned by its CID through my Pinata-API.
I want to pin it in front end through a public gateway because I don't want to expose my API keys. Now my concern is the availability of the public gateway.

Is the way I do it a good practice or is there improval?